# I don't understand how shifting 16 bits,8 bits,etc. with the combination of the '&' detects 1s in the even bits

Tags: c, architecture, binary, byte

I'm writing a program to detect if there are ones in the even bits. 0101 has ones in the even places for example. And this solution happens to work but I have no idea why.

What confuses me is that when we shift 16 bits to the right. For example with 0101 we're just creating 0000 0000 0000 0000 0101 right? Then we do an and with the original number so it'd be 0000 0000 0000 0000 0101 & 0000 0000 0000 0000 0101 is just the same number right? So if we do this shifting over and over and eventually x&1 I don't see how this helps anything to return 1 if allEvenbits.

```
/* 
 * allEvenBits - return 1 if all even-numbered bits in word set to 1
 *   Examples allEvenBits(0xFFFFFFFE) = 0, allEvenBits(0x55555555) = 1
 *   Legal ops: ! ~ & ^ | + << >>
 *   Max ops: 12
 *   Rating: 2
 */

int allEvenBits(int x) {
  //0xAA - OxFF are valid entries
  x = x & (x >> 16);
  x = x & (x >> 8);
  x = x & (x >> 4);
  x = x & (x >> 2);
  return x&1; 
}
```

Comment: Never use signed types like `int` when doing bitwise operations. `allEvenBits(0xFFFFFFFE)` will set the sign bit and then you'll get strange results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that integers (at least for the purpose of this exercise) are 32 bits long. So if you do a right shift of 16 bits on:

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0101
------------------- -------------------
  These  \          Right bits discarded
  bits are  \
  shifted 16   \
  positions right \ 
                     \
                        \
                           \
                    -------------------
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
Zeros enter on left
```

The rest of the shifts continue this process; in all, the total shift is 30 bit positions, so only the last two bits can have a value other than 0. The last bit will be 1 only if all bits in even positions are 1; the second-last bit is 1 pnly if all the bits in odd positions are 1.

In this case, the conjunction is 0, indicating that neither every even bit nor every odd bit is set. That's correct; only two even bits are set.

Comment: I don't see how this function could return one then because if it shifts so many times to the right then you'll lose all the values and everything will just be all zeroes

Comment: @esau the sum of the shifts is 30, so you don't lose *all* the bits. Two of them remain. One is the conjunction of all the bits in odd position s and the other in even positions.

Comment: yes, you're right. But this solution only works for very large numbers like 0x55555555 that fill up the whole 32 bit space. Because if it's a smaller number like 0x55 even though all bits are even, it'll be gone with all the shifting and the solution returns zero

Comment: If I could upvote your comment above, I would. It's what helped me understand this, thanks!

Comment: @Esau: "this solution only works for very large numbers like 0x55555555". True. But that's what is asked for. The high order bits are also even and odd positions.

Comment: I edited the answer with the idea from the comment you found helpful.